# Handle FileUploadBase.SizeLimitExceededException with Spring 2

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, jhipster

I have spring boot with jHipster and having this config at yml :

```
servlet:
  multipart:
    enabled: true
    max-file-size: 5MB
```

whenever I upload a file above 5 mb and below 10 mb the controller handle the exception ,however a file size above 10 mb it doesn't work  any idea ?

```
@ExceptionHandler(value=MaxUploadSizeExceededException.class)
public  ResponseEntity<Problem> handleFileSizeLimitExceeded(MaxUploadSizeExceededException ex,NativeWebRequest request) {
         Problem problem = Problem.builder()
                .withStatus(Status.OK)
                .with(MESSAGE_KEY, ErrorConstants.FILE_SIZE )
                .build();
            return create(ex, problem, request);

}
```

The exception is :
 `Maximum upload size exceeded; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (11064188) exceeds the configured maximum (10485760)]`

Comment: try to specify one more property `spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size: 5MB`

Comment: I did that same problem

Comment: please specify your controller method

Comment: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadBase$SizeLimitExceededException: the request was rejected because its size (6540589) exceeds the configured maximum (5242880)]  .....4 times repeating after I added   maxRequestSize : 5MB

Comment: please specify your controller method  ..what do u mean?

Comment: controller method like the following: ` @PostMapping(value = "/import", consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public void importData(@RequestPart("uploadedFile") MultipartFile uploadedFile) {...}`

Comment: or maybe you need to specify multiple exception classes under `@ExceptionHandler({ExceptionClass1, ExceptionClass2})`

Comment: Its locates in another  micro I have a security gateway blocking the file limit upload before reaching the actual controller  in the configuration gateway I added before   servlet:
    multipart:
      enabled: true
      maxFileSize : 5MB
      maxRequestSize : 5MB

Comment: did that before same issue